# Is it possible to add more tokens to already deployed contract

Tags: contract-development, tokens

I have created smart contract and deployed it. Now I realized that I would like to extend my ICO but of course use the same tokens.

If I create new smart contract with the same name of token it would be whole new token. How can I add more tokens for old contract?
Is there any way to generate new tokens that will be the same as from original contract so I can sell more of them using new contract but at the end those should all be the same tokens?

Like printing dollars, they are new dollars but can be used as old dollars.

Comment: Which standards or types of token did you initially create?

Did you use Open Zeppelin's framework or ...?

Need more details.

Comment: Nope, I used this one https://bitbucket.org/trbsi/ethcontract

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to have the relevant function and logic code in your original contract that would allow you to inflate the supply.  If you have not added this functionality then you will not be able to do it.

The other approach is to have some kill and migrate function where you can migrate the data and state from one contract to another new contract that has the new functionality to increase the supply.

Potentially there is another way but will need some research to see if its possible, you could try to create a new contract that someone how is able to check how many coins from your original supply an address has and then credit them the equivalent coins in the new contract that has the functionality to inflate the supply.